# Garbage data in database export-import using the same table collation

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'm using Adminer to dump a database and move it to a new database. Both databases are on the same MySQL server 5.5.5-10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 . Both databases use `latin1_swedish_ci` collation, as shown in Adminer.

These random character strings appear in the database tables, i.e. `bs00fgcb` for what should be a name, `hgaibbsf@example.org` for what should be an email, etc.

This data, of course, appears normal on the application front end before exporting the database, but appears as the garbage above after import into the other database and viewed with the other application.

This garbage data appears in the database dump when viewed with a text editor using UTF-8, before I import into the new database. No other data appears to be corrupted.

If I import the database dump before viewing it in a text editor, I get the same garbage data. I've tried exporting and importing the database multiple times.

This is the export file header:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.15  Distrib 10.0.36-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: example_sql
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.0.36-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

This appears to call a character for each table set upon import:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

Why I getting this garage data when exporting or importing? Where is it happening?

I don't want to try converting the database table collation being used by the active application before I export.

I used `select convert(binary convert(field_name using latin1) using utf8) from table_name` on one imported table, but it did nothing.

Comment: If the data is encoded, `latin1`, the editor might be mangling things when specifying UTF-8.  Can you get a hex dump of part of the data?

Comment: I tired that, but no luck; but that does make sense, as I have seen that issue before with opening differently encoded text files.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I'm not sure what the problem was: either Adminer when either exporting and/or importing; or, the table collations being `latin1_swedish_ci`, even though both databases used the same collation; or even a conflict between the very old linux version and newer MySQL versions on the server.

But I exported using mysqldump via SSH while forcing UTF, and then changed the  table collation to utf8_unicode_ci on the import database, and that worked.

So, export directly from MySQL using mysqldump while forcing utf8:

`mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 my_database > backup.sql`

Or use gzip, if needed:

`mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 my_database | gzip > backup.gz`

Then I set the table collation on the database to `utf8_unicode_ci` and imported the database with Adminer.

Comment: The database collation is irrelevant; what was the _column's_ character set?